Reduce wake-up Latency/Response Time std::condition_variable::wait_for
OS: vxWorks 7 23.09
C++17
Compiler: Clang
Hardware Platform: Intel 11th Gen i7 CPU
BSP: Intel Generic BSP 64-bits
I've 2 threads. One thread hereby refereed to as Ethernet Reader thread that as name suggest read data from socket and pushes it to std::queue and notifies the main thread (processing thread).
The main thread (processing thread) uses std::condition_variable::wait_for to yield CPU when their is no data to process. Earlier I used busy-wait design pattern for processing.

I wish to reduce the latency to wake up thread/task when I use std::condition_variable::wait_for.
Earlier when I don't use std::condition_variable::wait_for i.e. used busy-wait design pattern inside an infinite loop my entire processing time is 3-15 micro-seconds for processing ethernet data.
As I use std::condition_variable::wait_for the processing thread takes 50-250 micro-seconds just to wake-up. Rest of the processing is done within 15 micro-seconds.
It looks like the solution to problem (busy-wait) is more expensive than the cost of problem.
I'm looking for strategies to reduce wake latency if I put my processing thread has yielded the CPU in case their is no data to process.
I'm not fixated on std::condition_variable::wait_for and I'm ready to change my approach if something else provides better latency/response time.
Output:
Calling Notify All : 1731492554671893
Inside Wait For : 1731492554672106
Calling Notify All : 1731492557672289
Inside Wait For : 1731492557672506
Calling Notify All : 1731492560672740
Inside Wait For : 1731492560672901

Code:
wait_for_event.hpp
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <condition_variable>

namespace wfe
{
    enum class WaitForEventStatus : std::uint8_t
    {
        Error = 0,
        Timeout,
        NoTimeout,
        NoError  //Required for just wait
    };

    class WaitForEvent
    {
    private:
        std::mutex              mutex;
        std::condition_variable condition_variable;
    public:

        void notify_one(void) noexcept
        {
            this->condition_variable.notify_one();
        }

        void notify_all(void) noexcept
        {
            this->condition_variable.notify_all();
        }

        void wait(void)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
            this->condition_variable.wait(lock);
        }

        template <class Rep, class Period>
        WaitForEventStatus wait_for(const std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>& wait_time)
        {
            try
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                auto return_status = this->condition_variable.wait_for(lock, wait_time);
                if(return_status == std::cv_status::no_timeout)
                {
                    return WaitForEventStatus::NoTimeout;
                }
                else
                {
                    return WaitForEventStatus::Timeout;
                }
            }
            catch(const std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
                return WaitForEventStatus::Error;
            }
        }

        template <class Clock, class Duration>
        WaitForEventStatus wait_until(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock,Duration>& abs_time)
        {
            try
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                auto return_status = this->condition_variable.wait_until(lock, abs_time);
                if(return_status == std::cv_status::no_timeout)
                {
                    return WaitForEventStatus::NoTimeout;
                }
                else
                {
                    return WaitForEventStatus::Timeout;
                }
            }
            catch(const std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
                return WaitForEventStatus::Error;
            }
        }

        WaitForEvent() = default;
        ~WaitForEvent() = default;
    };
}

main.cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include "wait_for_event.hpp"

wfe::WaitForEvent event;

void thread_runner(void)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Code to read data from socket and push the data in queue
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(3));//Only for testing - not on live code
        std::cout << "Calling Notify All : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << std::endl;
        event.notify_all();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::thread t {thread_runner};
    while (true)
    {
        auto return_status = event.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        if(return_status == wfe::WaitForEventStatus::Timeout)
        {
            //std::cout << "WaitForEventStatus::Timeout\n";
        }
        else if(return_status == wfe::WaitForEventStatus::NoTimeout)
        {
            //std::cout << "WaitForEventStatus::NoTimeout\n";
            std::cout << "Inside Wait For : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}


I think you are out of luck. If you want a short response time standard C++ mechanisms will not help.

@0___________ Are their any C or OS specific mechanism that can help?

It is outside of your control, it depends on your CPU and your OS (thread scheduling, wakeups etc). If you want more control you need to run a real-time OS (and not share your application with many others running too)

@PepijnKramer Are their any OS specific mechanism that can help? I'm using RTOS (vxWorks). I've multiple threads/task between whom I'm sharing data.

Yes use an RTOS (real time operating system), you will have more control

@PepijnKramer vxWorks is the RTOS

@0___________ Oops I missed that

"Rest of the processing is done within 15 micro-seconds." - ¿What is the point of offloading this work into another thread? ¿Have you considered batched tasks transfers to reduce sync overhead per task?

@user7860670 The main thread is used to process data from different sensors sending data on different interfaces (e.g. Ethernet, CAN, RS-422, RS-485). The main thread contains control and binding logic. The processed data is further passed to next Real-Time Process for further processing. In this project response time is paramount. Having batched tasks transfers will introduce additional delay that will not be acceptable.

Is it really important for the data to be processed promptly? Or, do you merely need to know precisely when the data were received? I have worked on real-time applications in which precise information about the timing of measurements was needed in order to correctly interpret those measurements, but the results of that interpretation were not needed until hundreds or thousands of milliseconds later.

@SolomonSlow The data needs to be processed promptly. We have a processing deadline of few hundred micro-seconds else it would be considered system failure. The timing measurement is only to prove system is adhering to deadline.

In that case, I second what user7860670 said: I'd be looking at how I could design the system so that the processing is done in the same thread that received the data.

I think the only way to archive very low latency is to use software interrupt and process it in the ISR routine
Another option is to use lightweight sync primitives like binary semaphores. They do not track ownership and directly signal the waiting task
Event Flags (eventLib) are also efficient.

Will try binary semaphores and if it doesn't work, I'll try software interrupt.
